# Cracked Screen but no damage to display

Tags: display, dell-inspiron

I have a insperon 13 7352 2 in 1. I noticed the screen was cracked, but there is no distorting of the display. I was wondering if I need to replace it right away, or if its fine the way it is. I don't want to ignore it and then later have it completely fail and need a new laptop.

Comment: IMO, you answered your own question.

Comment: @CharlieRB How? Which one is it?

Comment: "*I don't want to ignore it and then later have it completely fail and need a new laptop*"...if it is a concern, have it repaired. We cannot make that call for you.

Answer (score 1):

A crack in the screen should not cause damage to your hardware, although the crack could worsen on the screen itself.

So eventually, the screen may need to be replaced.

The screen itself is a bit pricey from what I can see, usually around $145 for a new one.

[Amazon has one listed](https://amzn.com/B01AN4J8IC)

From there, you need to determine whether you are comfortable with installing it yourself.  Consider the price you paid for the laptop and the age of the machine before making any purchases.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Do you know where I can find just the external screen, it doesn't need a completely new LCD just the glass front part.

Comment: Or do you have to get both?

Comment: Can't say I know off the top of my head.

I would recommend doing some research regarding pricing and parts at your own pace, simply because you may realize its more work than its worth.